# Format a user inputted number into a common "Engine Size" pattern

Tags: php

I'm trying to format a given number into a simple pattern in PHP, used for a vehicle Engine Size display.

The pattern needs to be `[digit][dot][digit]` - i.e. `1.8` or `2.0` or `0.7`

I have zero control over validation of the data that is entered. I can only use what is given. However, it could follow any of these patterns:

`1`, `1.2`, `1600`, `1998.9`, `1920`

Given the examples above, here is what I would need to return:

`1` = `1.0`

`1.2` = `1.2`

`1600` = `1.6`

`1998.9` = `2.0`

`1920` = `1.9`

I've tried playing with `round()`, `floor()` and `number_format()` but I can't quite figure out a way to 'catch-all' given possibilities.

I could probably sit down and write a huge function to get this working, but I'm not too knowledgeable on optimising my PHP - so just wondering if there's a graceful solution that could exist?

Comment: What you expect for 1.64 ? 1.6 or 1.65 ?

Comment: @uxmal It would be 1.6 - no matter the length of the input number, the output must be [digit][dot][digit] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can abuse/exploit PHP's loose typing for this, then with some Regex "magic" a pinch of number formatting and `67bytes` - ad {waves hands} vola'

```
$inputs = [1, 1.2, 1600, 1998.9, 1920];

foreach($inputs as $input)
echo number_format(preg_replace(['/\./','/^(\d)/'],['','\1.'],$input),1)."\n";
```

Output

```
1.0
1.2
1.6
2.0
1.9
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50c1ef0cad9f8fe79d97125cd9521be09a2670a7)

Basically what I am doing is

1. `'/\./'` replace `.` with `''`

   - remove dots
2. `'/^(\d)/'` capture the first digit (group 1)

   - replace this match with itself (the first digit) and a dot `\1.`
3. Format it with 1 decimal place

Basically it places the decimal after the first number (no matter where it was), then rounds it to 1 place. So for `1998.9`

1. remove dots `19989`
2. add dot after first digit `1.9989`
3. format `2.0`

Because PHP is loosely typed it doesn't care if its a number like string or a number.  So we can just shift the decimal were we want it and PHP could care less ... lol  ... if it looks like a number, and smells like a number it must be a number.

***P.S.*** There are of course many ways to do the above, but this `preg_replace` was the first one I thought of that I could do in 1 line.

Cheers!

**UPDATE**

Here is one (golfed a bit) that doesn't use Regex

```
$inputs = [1, 1.2, 1600, 1998.9, 1920];

foreach($inputs as $input)
echo number_format((($i=str_replace(".","",$input))?substr($i,0,1).".".substr($i,1):$i),1)."\n";
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10172c6676b71300ff5314911f3dc1b31803e421)

Comment: Tested on a few variations and it works each time. Regex to the rescue yet again. I'm a sucker for a one-liner, thank you very much :)

Comment: Sure it was pretty simple.  `Tested on a few variations` the only thing that will brake it is alpha chars, but that would probably break any solution to this.  One could use `substr` to add the `.`  eg. `substr($str, 0,1).".".substr($str,1)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone with better math skills can come up with a cleaner solution than using a while loop, but this does what you ask for:

```
function formatNumber($num)
{
    // We divide the number until it's less than 10
    while ($num >= 10) {
        $num = $num / 10;
    }

    // Now we round the number to one decimal precision.    
    return round($num, 1);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/QktJ0)